# Get Session info for remote computer?

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way to get the session info from a remote windows server (Assuming you have admin credentials).  For example, if you open Task Manager and go to the Users tab, that is the info I want...

- User
- (Session)
- ID (Session) Status
- Client Name Session (Name)

Programmatic in C# would be best but I could also wrap a cmd line tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/).

Comment: Yes. Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for :)